# iPhone 4s 6.1.3 Update to IOS 6

Tags: ios, upgrade

I have iPhone 4s with firmware IOS 6.1.3, i like upgrade to IOS 7. Actually signed firmware for iPhone 4s is IOS 9.1. Is Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you would need Apple to start signing iOS 7 for that hardware. Since Apple is signing iOS 9 it's not signing 8 and lower anymore. Basically, upgrading to anything but the latest is essentially a downgrade and not supported unless you've already jailbroken or made arrangements to fake out the code signing needed for an iOS update.

Basically, you can stick with what you have or go all the way to 9 at this point.

Comment: Older firware can be downloaded & installed. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to update using iTunes, it will attempt to update to the newest firmware supported for that device (8.3 for the 4s). However, there is another way...

First go to http://www.ipswdownloader.com & download the desired firmware version for your iPhone (the download is actually from Apple). Now go to iTunes with the phone connected, go to the Summary page for the iPhone & Option-click (& I don't know the modifier on Windows) the Check For Update button. The modified click will throw a file open dialog, & you select the IPSW file you've just downloaded. Proceed as for any other update, & wait until done.

Answer (score -2):

You may be able to!

There's a tool called OdysseusOTA (windows version released yesterday!) that lets 4S users restore to unsigned firmwares.

Before you do though, you'll need to use p0sixpwn to jailbreak your device (if not already). Also, if you're on windows, install cygwin.

Take a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/3ttkjx/release_odysseus_for_windows/ and downlaod some of the bundles from [here](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/b1z64roy512wd/FirmwareBundles).

Do your research though. Upgrading is definitely possible, but I'm not sure on specifics.

(sorry, only two links as I'm a guest :( )

Comment: Why did this get downvotes? It's correct, it does work.